# How to put a shadow in all four sides of an image?

Tags: html, css

I need to know how to put shadow in all four sides of a div. I need a little explanation of:

filter:
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow

Comment: `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow` is for Internet Explorer v9 and below (from recollection please correct me if I'm wrong), which applies box shadows to IE only and can be added with the other box shadow options i.e. `-moz-`, `-webkit-`, etc.. I also remember those shadows looking seriously ugly as sin on older IE versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you shadow on all 4 sides:

```
div.shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/974Dm/4/)

The first two `0px`'s mean that the shadow won't explicitly protrude either left/right or up/down. The `10px` gives it enough blur to protrude out all edges. The `#000` is the color of the shadow. You can play around with it to get the look you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use box-shadow

```
.class-name{

   box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;   
             /* horizontal, vertical, blurr-radius, colour  */


}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Box-Shadow

CSS3 box-shadow property has following attributes: ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp))

`box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;`

The main prefix for shadow to support latest browsers is `box-shadow`.

There are 2 other prefix available that I recommend to use for older Mozilla and Webkit:

- `-moz-box-shadow`
- `-webkit-box-shadow`

Try it:

```
img{
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #000000;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #000000;
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #000000;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/974Dm/5/)

[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)